# Oracle - what happens with the transaction in case of ORA-03135 connection lost?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I need to run on production environemnt a delete statement that takes a lot of time and the server is closing any connection after 30 minutes (ORA-03135 from what I see in the logs).

What will happen if I start the delete statement and the server will close the connection? Will the statement finish executing on the server or will it shut it down immediately and rollback? Can SQL*Plus `set autocommit on` command help in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the manual:https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT037

> **End of a Transaction** 
>   
> A transaction ends when any of the following actions occurs:
>
> - A user issues a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement without a SAVEPOINT clause.
> - A user runs a DDL command such as CREATE, DROP, RENAME, or ALTER.
> - A user exits normally from most Oracle Database utilities and tools, causing the current transaction to be implicitly committed. The commit behavior when a user disconnects is application-dependent and configurable.
> - A client process **terminates abnormally**, causing the transaction to be **implicitly rolled back** using metadata stored in the transaction
>     table and the undo segment.

Comment: Is it reasonable for your delete to take > 30 mins?